# using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table doesn't work in a UWP project

Tags: azure, unity-game-engine, nuget, visual-studio-2019, hololens

We are creating an HoloLens 2 app.

Our installed NuGet packages are:

- Hyak.Common
- Microsoft.Azure.Common
- Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table
- Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core

We want to use the library "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" for our Azure Storage Account table storage.

We are working with Unity 2018.4.22f1 and Visual Studio 2019. When we try to use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table we get this error:

The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Everytime we reinstall the nuget "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table" it works at first. When we restart visual studio 2019 the error appears again

[image: 1]

Comment: Also, you could also share a minimal, reproducible sample with us and we can troubleshoot your issue with it.

Comment: Every package is the latest stable version.

Comment: Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

> using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table doesn't work in a UWP project

Please try the following steps:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**--> **Manage Extensions** in case some extensions cause this and after that, you should restart VS

**2)** delete all component caches under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders), delete `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project.

**4)** try to create a new project and then install these four nuget packages to test whether this strange behavior appears in the new project.

Or you could create a new project to migrate your old project into the new project to test whether the issue still persists.

If still faces the same error, please try **step 5**

**5)** [repair vs in vs installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or if there is any update for VS, please update it.

**Update**

=============================

After a deep research, I think the issue is that your uwp project's target version is not compatible with that package's version.

So the solution is that you should

set the uwp project min target to `>=Windows 10 Fall Createors Update(10.0;Build 16299)` and target version `>=Windows 10,version 1809(10.0,Build 17763)`.

Also, use the latest nuget package **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table** `1.0.7` version

Comment: Same Problem. After Step 5 The error only showed up in Unity but not in Visual Studio 2019 anymore. After restarting my VM the error massage appeared in Unity and Visual Studio 2019 again.

Comment: Scan / Updates did not change a thing

Comment: Hi, I think I may have spotted your problem. The issue is that your uwp project's target version is not compatible with that package's version. I assume you used the latest version `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table 1.0.7 version`. For me, set the uwp project min target to >=`Windows 10 Fall Createors Update(10.0;Build 16299)` and target version >=`Windows 10,version 1809(10.0,Build 17763)`.

Comment: I changed Target Device to any device, Architecture to x64, Build Type to D3D, Target SDK Version to 10.0.17763.0, Minimum Platform Version to 10.0.16299.0, Visual Studio Version to Visual Studio 2019, Build and Run on to Local Machine and Build configuration to Release. There is still the same problem.
We use Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table 1.0.7.

Comment: ohh.....okay. Maybe you can try to reinstall unity and also vs2019.

Comment: Using Unity 2019.4.4f1 (64-bit) fixed the problem in Visual Studio but it's still in the Unity Console.

Comment: Please try to clean and then rebuild the project. If the error did not appear in VS, I think you could mark the answer since we discussed the issue in VS2019 here.